# pandas groupby excluding when a column takes some value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Is there a way to exclude rows that take certain values when aggregating?

For example:

```
ID | Company | Cost 
1  | Us      | 2
1  | Them    | 1
1  | Them    | 1
2  | Us      | 1
2  | Them    | 2
2  | Them    | 1
```

I would like to do a `groupby` and `sum` but ignoring whenever a row is `Company="us"`.

The result should be something like this:

```
ID | Sum of cost
1  | 2
2  | 3
```

I solved it by doing this, but I want to know if there's a smarter solution:

```
df_agg = df[df['Company']!="Us"][['ID','Cost']].groupby(['ID']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
   ID Company  Cost
0   1      Us     2
1   1    Them     1
2   1    Them     1
3   2      Us     1
4   2    Them     2
5   2    Them     1
6   3      Us     1 <- added new row for see difference
```

If need filter first and not matched groups (if exist) are not important use:

```
df1 = df[df.Company!="Us"].groupby('ID', as_index=False).Cost.sum()
print (df1)
   ID  Cost
0   1     2
1   2     3


df1 = df.query('Company!="Us"').groupby('ID', as_index=False).Cost.sum()
print (df1)
   ID  Cost
0   1     2
1   2     3
```

If need all groups `ID` with `Cost=0` for `Us` first set `Cost` to `0` and then aggregate:

```
df2 = (df.assign(Cost = df.Cost.where(df.Company!="Us", 0))
         .groupby('ID', as_index=False).Cost
         .sum())
print (df2)
   ID  Cost
0   1     2
1   2     3
2   3     0
```